# Prepared MySQL statement with upper and like

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I started off with:

```
$check = $db->prepare("SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `this_table` WHERE UPPER(`name`) LIKE ?")or die($db->error);
```

Which doesn't work, and doesn't return any rows. Tried getting further into it, and came to:

```
$check = $db->prepare("SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `this_table` WHERE UPPER(`name`) LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')")or die($db->error);
```

But no joy either. Have tried my parameter both in all caps and regular casing. No difference. How to combine these three?

Comment: Show us sample data that you're trying to match.

Comment: maybe there isn't really a result :p the code presented is not enough, you should post some more

Comment: Your first prepare statement is good enough.  Unless in the created like is not wrapped in quotation `LIKE '%SOMECHARACTERS%'`

Comment: String comparisons with LIKE are case insensitive unless one of the operands is a binary string, so normally no need for `UPPER()` at all, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: The descriptions of the observed behavior as "doesn't work" and "no joy" provides little insight into what problem you are experiencing. Is the prepare throwing an error, or is the execution of the statement not returning any rows, or returning too many rows. It's impossible to tell from the information you've provided. Anyone providing an "answer" to your question is just guessing what behavior you are observing.

Comment: @VMai: or one of the strings being compared is case sensitive, for example, if the `name` column is defined with a case sensitive collation (i.e. the name of the characterset ends with _cs rather than _ci), or the client characterset is case sensitive.  Excerpt from 5.5 Reference Manual **"Normally, if any expression in a string comparison is case sensitive, the comparison is performed in case-sensitive fashion."** [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

Comment: @spencer7593 Sometimes it's more productive to leave the keyboard and call it a day instead of writing low quality comments as I did yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the LIKE as a variable wrapped in %:

```
$val = '%some-value%';
$q = $db->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM this_table WHERE UPPER(name) LIKE ?" );
$q->bindValue( 1, $val );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** How to combine these three?

**A:** There's not sufficient information in your question to know what behavior you're observing (prepare is failing with error message, execute is failing with error message, the execution is successful, but fetch isn't returning any rows, or is returning unexpected rows... we're just guessing.

The syntax of both of the SQL statements you posted appears to be valid. (From the information provided, we have no way of validating the identifiers, the datatypes, privileges, etc.)

We note that if the `name` column is defined with a case insensitive collation (i.e. a characterset ending in `_ci`, and client characterset is case insensitive, then the use of the `UPPER()` function is likely not required, but it's valid.  (We're guessing here that the `name` column is defined as a VARCHAR column, but again, that's really just a guess.

To be consistent, we'd kind of expect BOTH sides of the LIKE comparison would be wrapped in UPPER() function...

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.name
  FROM `this_table` t
 WHERE UPPER(t.name) LIKE UPPER( ? )
       ^^^^^              ^^^^^
```

If you are expecting a wildcard match, where `name` value of 'abcd' will match 'bc', then you'd need the value you supply in the bindParam would include the wild card characters.

If the value you are supplying is just `'bc'`, then you can include the wild card characters as you've shown in your second example, with `CONCAT` function and literal `'%'` characters.

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.name 
  FROM `this_table` t
 WHERE UPPER(t.name) LIKE CONCAT('%', UPPER( ? ), '%')
       ^^^^^                          ^^^^^
```

Beyond that, we're only guessing at the behavior you are observing with the information you've provided.